# Remove embedded subtitles from an .mkv file?

Tags: subtitles, matroska

Is there a way I can remove subtitle data from an .mkv?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use [MkvToolNix](https://web.archive.org/web/20151105204525/https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/).  The `mkvmerge` tool can do exactly what you want. It's a very capable Matroska manipulator and should be able to remove any kind of stream from an MKV without recoding all the other streams.

- On Windows, download the latest version from [here](https://www.videohelp.com/software/MKVToolNix). Just run the installer.
- On Linux, you can find the package `mkvtoolnix` in your repository, or alternatively download them from [the homepage](https://mkvtoolnix.download/downloads.html).
- On OS X, the easiest way would be to install `mkvtoolnix` through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

I think one of these commands will do what you want:

```
# assume input.mkv has 3 subtitle tracks
# remove subtitle track 2 (copy 1&3) from input.mkv & save to output.mkv
mkvmerge -o output.mkv --subtitle-tracks 1,3 input.mkv

# remove all subtitles (copy none)
mkvmerge -o output.mkv --no-subtitles input.mkv
```

Comment: I have found the output files from MkvToolNix (mkvmerge) to be unusable by some players & converter (ArcSoft VideoConverter in particular - I was trying to strip the subtitles prior to converting them for viewing on my iPhone).

Comment: Usage note: The track numbers supplied to `--stracks` are not 1 (first subtitle), 2 (second), 3 (third), etc. Use `mkvinfo input.mkv` to enumerate the tracks in the .mkv first (e.g. track 0 may be video; 1,2,3 may be audio; 4,5,6 may be subtitles) then use the 0-based track number with the `--stracks` switch. In quack's  example above this might be `--stracks 4,6`

Comment: To confirm, does the GUI version of the program also remove subtitles without re-encoding?

Comment: @HashimAziz yes, mkvtoolnix is incapable of re-encoding. all operations on the stream level are copying.