# How can I remove soft coded subtitles from mkv file?

Tags: subtitles, matroska

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove embedded subtitles from an .mkv file?](https://superuser.com/questions/98399/remove-embedded-subtitles-from-an-mkv-file)

How can I remove soft coded subtitles from a `.mkv` file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Install [MKVtoolnix](https://web.archive.org/web/20151105204525/https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/). It's a set of free tools for Windows, Linux and Mac OS X.

- On Windows, download the latest version from [here](https://www.videohelp.com/software/MKVToolNix). Just run the installer.
- On Linux, you can find the packages `mkvtoolnix` and `mkvtoolnix-gui` in your repository, or alternatively download them from [the homepage](https://mkvtoolnix.download/downloads.html).
- On OS X, the easiest way would be to install `mkvtoolnix` through [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

After installing, you just need to run:

```
mkvmerge --no-subtitles input.mkv -o output.mkv
```

As easy as that. There's also a GUI, which allows you to remux streams as you like.

[image]